# iOS bundle invalid

Tags: ios, armv7, armv6

My project no longer builds.  I don't know if it has to do with my system crashing then I uploaded a later version of xcode, using 
The complete error message is xcode version 4.6

```
"This bundle is invalid. When supporting iPhone electable must support amrv6 architecture , unless Ur Required Device Cablties include the :armv7" capability.
```

I tried calling apple, after about  a week they said it was a code signing issue and I had to read there docs, which I did nothing about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are compiling an application for ARMv7 only, but not specifying in your main plist that you require an ARMv7 or newer device.

Either compile for ARMv6, or set the required property.